# Unity how to check for color match

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors

I am using Unity 5 and wanted to check on collision if two game object material have the same matching color and to take action if the colours don't match. I am using the c# code below:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{

    if(col.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color != this.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color)
    {
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    } 
}
```

This doesn't appear to work properly as the sometimes the gameobject gets destroyed even when the color matches. Just wondering if there is another way to check for color matches?

Comment: Did you try comparing each component (rgba or xyzw) separately? It is a pain but works,.

Comment: The reason it fails is because you are not comparing two colors, but two `Color` objects for equality (which they most likely aren't, even if they hold the same values). If you want to compare the colors you would have to compare each individual component (r,g,b and maybe even alpha) if they have the same values (converting to `Vector4` and comparing might also work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to save `color` objects in new temporary variables and then do the comparison:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    Color myColor = GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
    Color otherColor = col.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
    if(myColor.Equals(otherColor))
    {
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    } 
}
```

**If this doesn't work:**

Write extension method for `color` and use it like this:

**Extension class:**

```
static class Extension
{
    public static bool IsEqualTo(this Color me, Color other)
    {
        return me.r == other.r && me.g == other.g && me.b == other.b && me.a == other.a;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    Color myColor = GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
    Color otherColor = col.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
    if(myColor.IsEqualTo(otherColor))
    {
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I think this won't really work because the r,g,b,a components of a Color are floating values. So lots of times two colours won't match because in one Color red is 0.554675768 and in the other it's 0.554675767. I suggest using Mathf.Approximately( ) because it includes an epsilon in the comparison. Example: Mathf.Approximately(color1.r, color2.red).